# UNION ALL and SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to union 2 tables,2 tables have same columns name.
After union all,then add where condition

i have tried to add bracket in the union section

```
(SELECT * FROM MYDB.user 
UNION ALL select * 
from MYDB.user_old)
WHERE userid="158"
```

but doesnt work...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 4):

You have to alias the `UNION` queries and treat them like a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM MYDB.user 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT * FROM MYDB.user_old) t
WHERE userid="158"
```

Answer (score 1):

/*you can use with and do it*/

```
with as temp(
(SELECT * FROM MYDB.user 
UNION ALL select * 
from MYDB.user_old)

select * from temp 
where userid="158"
```

Answer (score 0):

use subquery and it is always have to be same number of column in times of union operation so use explicit column name in selection

```
select * from 
(select userid,col2,......coln from MYDB.user
union all
select userid,col2......coln from MYDB.user_old
) a WHERE userid="158"
```

if userid column datatype is int then use  `WHERE userid=158`

Comment: @YehCheez I have not understood what you wan to say

Comment: @YehCheez have you noticed the answer i am given same answer given later .04sec of me another person and got 4 upvote

Comment: @YehCheez then help it to make is also useful answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `select * from` outside the union clause. like below:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM MYDB.user 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM MYDB.user_old
) tmp
WHERE userid='158'
```

Comment: If a thing's worth saying, it's worth saying thrice